# Is there something that we don't know about tunnels to sky or similar things?

Tags: prophets, adam-and-eve

I'm very interested about the story of our father the prohpet Adam (peace be upon him) as he is a source of guidance for mankind.

My question is about something that I can not understand with the little I know.

I stumbled many times upon something about the death of Adam (Peace be upon him) as reported by *Ibn kathir* and other oulam'a, and that I find very strange:

> Abdullah Ibn Al-Imam Ahmad Ibn Hanbal narrated that Ubai Ibn Ka'b said:
>
> When Adam's death was near, he said to his children:
>
> 'O my children, indeed, I feel an appetite **for the fruits of Paradise**.'
>
> **So they went away searching for what Adam had requested**. They met with the angels, who had with them his shroud and what he was to be embalmed with. They said to them:
>
> 'O Children of Adam, what are you searching for? What do you want? Where are you going?'
>
> They said:
>
> 'Our father is sick and has an appetite for the fruits of Paradise'.
>
> The angels said to them:
>
> 'Go back, for your father is going to meet his end soon.'...

I found this at least in
http://www.alim.org/library/biography/stories/content/SOP/34/1/Adam/Adam%27s%20Death#sthash.ceiXHyvD.dpuf) and
http://www.islamawareness.net/Prophets/adam.html

I wonder where the children of Adam were looking for the fruit of paradise?
paradise is not on earth and no human is supposed to ascend to the sky.

Is there something that we don't know about tunnels to sky or similar things ?